# Abstract example in spring

Tags: spring, abstract-class, abstract

Best code practice for not duplicate your code in spring controller by abstract.

I've got two controllers for example

```
@Controller
public class DoSomethingController {

    private Entity helpfulMethod(Form form) {
        Entity e = new Entity();
        return e;
    }
    @PostMapping("/something")
    public String something(Form form){
        helpfulMethod(form);
    }
}

@Controller
public class DoSomethingElseController {

    private Entity helpfulMethod(Form form) {
        Entity e = new Entity();
        return e;
    }

    @PostMapping("/somethingElse")
    public String somethingElse(Form form){
        helpfulMethod(form);
    }
}
```

How to take helpfulMethod out and connect them from outside using abstract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to introduce a super class for both the controllers

```
public abstract class BaseDoSomethingController {

    protected Entity helpfulMethod(Form form) {
        Entity e = new Entity();
        return e;
    }
}
```

and let both your controllers inherit the base class

```
@Controller
public class DoSomethingController extends BaseDoSomethingController {

    @PostMapping("/something")
    public String something(Form form){
        helpfulMethod(form);
    }
}
```

and the same for the second controller